# Separate JSON Arrays in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have uploaded a JSON file into PostgreSQL 10, but my output is the following:

```json
{
  "type":"name",
  "properties":{
    "name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
  }
}
```

```json
[
  {
    "type":"Feature",
    "geometry":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[
        [
          [
            -69.63156338410452,
            18.423064855125194
          ],
          [
            -69.63158484940756,
            18.42306049063717
          ],
          [
            -69.6316055531327,
            18.42316231511968
          ],
          [
            -69.63158408782962,
            18.4231666796077
          ],
          [
            -69.63156338410452,
            18.423064855125194
          ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties":{
      "id":579,
      "top":2087416.483723811,
      "left":-7751401.453397826,
      "right":-7751399.014997826,
      "bottom":2087404.291723811
    }
  },
  {
    "type":"Feature",
    "geometry":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[
        [
          [
            -69.63158408782962,
            18.4231666796077
          ],
          [
            -69.6316055531327,
            18.42316231511968
          ],
          [
            -69.6316262568703,
            18.42326413966371
          ],
          [
            -69.63160479156727,
            18.423268504151732
          ],
          [
            -69.63158408782962,
            18.4231666796077
          ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties":{
      "id":580,
      "top":2087404.291723811,
      "left":-7751401.453397826,
      "right":-7751399.014997826,
      "bottom":2087392.099723811
    }
  },
  {
    "type":"Feature",
    "geometry":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[
        [
          [
            -69.63160479156727,
            18.423268504151732
          ],
          [
            -69.6316262568703,
            18.42326413966371
          ],
          [
            -69.63164696062047,
            18.423365964269255
          ],
          [
            -69.6316254953174,
            18.42337032875728
          ],
          [
            -69.63160479156727,
            18.423268504151732
          ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties":{
      "id":581,
      "top":2087392.099723811,
      "left":-7751401.453397826,
      "right":-7751399.014997826,
      "bottom":2087379.907723811
    }
  },
  {
    "type":"Feature",
    "geometry":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[
        [
          [
            -69.6316254953174,
            18.423370328757276
          ],
          [
            -69.63164696062047,
            18.423365964269255
          ],
          [
            -69.6316676643831,
            18.423467788936325
          ],
          [
            -69.63164619908007,
            18.423472153424346
          ],
          [
            -69.6316254953174,
            18.423370328757276
          ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties":{
      "id":582,
      "top":2087379.9077238112,
      "left":-7751401.453397826,
      "right":-7751399.014997826,
      "bottom":2087367.7157238112
    }
  },
  {
    "type":"Feature",
    "geometry":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[
        [
          [
            -69.63164619908007,
            18.423472153424346
          ],
          [
            -69.6316676643831,
            18.423467788936325
          ],
          [
            -69.63168836815828,
            18.423569613664906
          ],
          [
            -69.63166690285523,
            18.42357397815293
          ],
          [
            -69.63164619908007,
            18.423472153424346
          ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties":{
      "id":583,
      "top":2087367.7157238112,
      "left":-7751401.453397826,
      "right":-7751399.014997826,
      "bottom":2087355.5237238111
    }
  },
  {
    "type":"Feature",
    "geometry":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[
        [
          [
            -69.63166690285523,
            18.42357397815293
          ],
          [
            -69.63168836815828,
            18.423569613664906
          ],
          [
            -69.63170907194598,
            18.423671438455013
          ],
          [
            -69.63168760664291,
            18.423675802943034
          ],
          [
            -69.63166690285523,
            18.42357397815293
          ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties":{
      "id":584,
      "top":2087355.5237238111,
      "left":-7751401.453397826,
      "right":-7751399.014997826,
      "bottom":2087343.331723811
    }
  },
  {
    "type":"Feature",
    "geometry":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[
        [
          [
            -69.63158484940756,
            18.42306049063717
          ],
          [
            -69.63160631471062,
            18.423056126149138
          ],
          [
            -69.63162701843578,
            18.423157950631648
          ],
          [
            -69.6316055531327,
            18.42316231511968
          ],
          [
            -69.63158484940756,
            18.42306049063717
          ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties":{
      "id":596,
      "top":2087416.483723811,
      "left":-7751399.014997827,
      "right":-7751396.576597827,
      "bottom":2087404.291723811
    }
  },
  {
    "type":"Feature",
    "geometry":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[
        [
          [
            -69.6316055531327,
            18.42316231511968
          ],
          [
            -69.63162701843578,
            18.423157950631648
          ],
          [
            -69.63164772217337,
            18.423259775175687
          ],
          [
            -69.6316262568703,
            18.42326413966371
          ],
          [
            -69.6316055531327,
            18.42316231511968
          ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties":{
      "id":597,
      "top":2087404.291723811,
      "left":-7751399.014997827,
      "right":-7751396.576597827,
      "bottom":2087392.099723811
    }
  },
  {
    "type":"Feature",
    "geometry":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[
        [
          [
            -69.6316262568703,
            18.42326413966371
          ],
          [
            -69.63164772217337,
            18.423259775175687
          ],
          [
            -69.63166842592354,
            18.423361599781227
          ],
          [
            -69.63164696062047,
            18.423365964269255
          ],
          [
            -69.6316262568703,
            18.42326413966371
          ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties":{
      "id":598,
      "top":2087392.099723811,
      "left":-7751399.014997827,
      "right":-7751396.576597827,
      "bottom":2087379.907723811
    }
  },
  {
    "type":"Feature",
    "geometry":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[
        [
          [
            -69.63164696062047,
            18.423365964269255
          ],
          [
            -69.63166842592354,
            18.423361599781227
          ],
          [
            -69.6316891296862,
            18.423463424448297
          ],
          [
            -69.6316676643831,
            18.423467788936325
          ],
          [
            -69.63164696062047,
            18.423365964269255
          ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties":{
      "id":599,
      "top":2087379.9077238112,
      "left":-7751399.014997827,
      "right":-7751396.576597827,
      "bottom":2087367.7157238112
    }
  },
  {
    "type":"Feature",
    "geometry":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[
        [
          [
            -69.6316676643831,
            18.423467788936325
          ],
          [
            -69.6316891296862,
            18.423463424448297
          ],
          [
            -69.63170983346134,
            18.423565249176885
          ],
          [
            -69.63168836815828,
            18.423569613664906
          ],
          [
            -69.6316676643831,
            18.423467788936325
          ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties":{
      "id":600,
      "top":2087367.7157238112,
      "left":-7751399.014997827,
      "right":-7751396.576597827,
      "bottom":2087355.5237238111
    }
  },
  {
    "type":"Feature",
    "geometry":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[
        [
          [
            -69.63168836815828,
            18.423569613664906
          ],
          [
            -69.63170983346134,
            18.423565249176885
          ],
          [
            -69.63173053724903,
            18.423667073966993
          ],
          [
            -69.63170907194598,
            18.423671438455013
          ],
          [
            -69.63168836815828,
            18.423569613664906
          ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties":{
      "id":601,
      "top":2087355.5237238111,
      "left":-7751399.014997827,
      "right":-7751396.576597827,
      "bottom":2087343.331723811
    }
  },
  {
    "type":"Feature",
    "geometry":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[
        [
          [
            -69.63160631471062,
            18.423056126149138
          ],
          [
            -69.6316277800137,
            18.42305176166112
          ],
          [
            -69.63164848373884,
            18.423153586143624
          ],
          [
            -69.63162701843578,
            18.423157950631648
          ],
          [
            -69.63160631471062,
            18.423056126149138
          ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties":{
      "id":613,
      "top":2087416.483723811,
      "left":-7751396.576597827,
      "right":-7751394.138197826,
      "bottom":2087404.291723811
    }
  }
]
```

There are numerous polygons contained in this field. I'd like to be able to separate them into different rows for each polygon and into type, name and properties columns. Is this achievable in PostgreSQL?

For example:

| Type | ID | Properties | Geometries |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Feature | 579 | "left": -7751401.453397826,"top": 2087416.483723811, "right": -7751399.014997826, "bottom": 2087404.291723811 | [-69.63156338410452, 18.423064855125194],[-69.63158484940756, 18.42306049063717],[-69.6316055531327, 18.42316231511968],[-69.63158408782962, 18.4231666796077],[-69.63156338410452, 18.423064855125194] |

Comment: Please do not use an image to show textual information. Copy and paste the `jsonb` data into your question. Then folks would have something they can construct an example around. Also an example of the output you want would be helpful.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver That's it formatted again now with the way I'd like the data to be displayed in PostgreSQL. Can anyone offer me any help in achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two bits of json in the string above. First,

```
"{"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}}"
```

And then an array which looks much better with proper indentation [indented](https://json-indent.com/) (results [here](https://pastecode.io/s/Meta9VBDPc)):

```
[
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            -69.63156338410452,
            18.423064855125194
          ],
          [
            -69.63158484940756,
            18.42306049063717
          ],
          [
            -69.6316055531327,
            18.42316231511968
          ],
          [
            -69.63158408782962,
            18.4231666796077
          ],
          [
            -69.63156338410452,
            18.423064855125194
          ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "id": 579,
      "top": 2087416.483723811,
      "left": -7751401.453397826,
      "right": -7751399.014997826,
      "bottom": 2087404.291723811
    }
  },
```

So, I'll assume all the objects have the same structure, similar as above. Let's put the json into a table for convenience...

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( d jsonb );
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('the above json data')
```

The following should do what you want, including conversion to postgres geometric types:

```
SELECT
typ,
BOX( POINT((prop->>'left')::FLOAT,  (prop->>'top')::FLOAT),
     POINT((prop->>'right')::FLOAT, (prop->>'bottom')::FLOAT) ) bbox,
     REPLACE(REPLACE((geom->'coordinates')->>0,'[','('),']',')')::POLYGON
FROM (
SELECT 
    elem->>'type'         AS typ,
    elem->'properties'    AS prop,
    elem->'geometry'      AS geom
FROM (
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(d) elem FROM foo
) f1
)f2;
```

However, processing this kind of json in a SQL query is not flexible, so if you have several types of geometry (not just polygons) or if the json structure can vary, it would be better to process it in a more suitable language before using SQL.

Comment: Thanks Bob! Tried your code but PostgreSQL is throwing this error when I try to execute ERROR:  cannot extract elements from an object
SQL state: 22023

Comment: Is it "cannot extract elements from a scalar"?

Comment: Sure, just use (prop->>'id')::INTEGER ; you could also use elem->'properties'->>'id'

Comment: I tried again from scratch and it worked perfectly! Thank you Bob!

Comment: Good! Note there are a ton of json functions and operators in postgres listed here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html

Comment: Hi Bob, is there anyway to extract the properties part of the Array as a whole so that the PostgreSQL row would read as {"location_id":"579",  "top":2087416.483723811, "left":-7751401.453397826, "bottom":2087404.291723811, "right":-7751401.453397826}